# Android, grid, three equal width columns (33%) filled with images

Tags: android, image, grid

I try to many times without success to create grid (image gallery) which look same on all devices. Usually easy task...seems that I here miss something. To rephrase question: grid columns must fill with of device screen, images must be resized to fit width and must retain proportion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GridView and set the columns to 3 then assign you adapter as needed.

Another option is you use a LinearLayout for each row and assign the weight of each object to .33 of the total weight.

Comment: FYI: weight doesn't have to add up to 1. You can use 1 for each of the weights and it'll work just as well as .33.

Comment: How does one assign weight? Example?

Comment: in your layout file android:layout_weight=1 or .33